# Nao robot stopped recognizing and responding to spoken words

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I'm working with two Nao robots. Their speech recognition abilities have been working alright so far, but recently they just stopped working altogether.

I am using Choregraphe and I can enter words in the dialog box and the robot will respond as intended, but when I speak out words, the robot will either not even recognize words being spoken, or will just display: `Human: <...>` and that's it. I have tried using autonomous life on and off, creating a simple dialog that only has one line of functionality, like: "u:(_*) Hello.", and it doesn't do anything.

In autonomous life mode the robot's eyes go blue and Nao nods occasionally as if it would hear words, but I get no response and see nothing in the console.

The robot I have is Nao model 6 (the dark grey one and as far as I know the newest model).

However if I use a speech recognition box, Nao will understand the spoken words, just not in the dialog. Do you have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i had a simmilar issue with Pepper.
I also encountered recognition stopping to work.
In my Choregraph log I had:

```
[WARN ] Dialog.StrategyRemote.personalData :prepare:0 FreeSpeechToText is not available
```

So the support let me know that:

> The problem you observed happened because Pepper got a timeout from
>   the Nuance Remote server, she will consider that the server is
>   unavailable and will not try to contact it again for one hour (during
>   which Free Speech will not work). This could be because the server is
>   indeed unavailable, or because of network issues.
>
> Fortunately to workaround a bad network you can change those
>   parameters, with ALSpeechRecognition.setParameter(parameter_name,
>   parameter_value)
>
> The parameters that will interest you are:
>
> RemoteTimeout: How long Pepper waits for a response from the Nuance
>   Remote server, in milliseconds. Default value: 10000.0 (ms)
>   RemoteTryAgain: Number of minutes before trying to use Nuance Remote
>   again after a timeout. Default value: 60.0 (minutes)
>
> Note that you will need to reset those values again after each boot.

Maybe that can also help you with Nao.

Also I learned that the Remote ASR seems to have a limit of about 200-250 invocations per day.

Comment: a strange problem, I even performed a factory reset, just in case. Just now it worked for a moment, now reverted back to interpreting everything as "...". I'll give it a go and see what happens. Thanks.